# Magento 2 translate the "You added ... to your shopping cart." line

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, localisation, js-translation

I'm trying to translate the "You added ... to your shopping cart." line in my Magento 2 installation.
I have already a **.csv** file in: **"app/design/themevendor/themename/i18n/"** with all the lines translated, 
and I have also translated the lines into **"vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php"** but the line that comes out when you add a to cart a product is still in English!

Also, this line has the last part, **"shopping cart"** as a link, the ones I have translated were just normal lines, so I think the one I'm trying to translate, is built from 2 parts, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using following line in i18n on theme as translation source

```
"You added %1 to your shopping cart."
```

then change it to

```
"You added %1 to your <a href=""%2"">shopping cart</a>."
```

**Example :**

```
"You added %1 to your <a href=""%2"">shopping cart</a>.","Du lade %1 in din <a href=""%2"">varukorg</a>"
```

Instead of

```
"You added %1 to your shopping cart.","Du lade %1 in din varukorg"
```

Answer (score 4):

I have actually managed to find the solution myself, the right file to edit is: 
**"vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/messages/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml"**

Answer (score 0):

@alexcr, that file should be extended in app/design/CUSTOM/THEME/Magento_Checkout/templates/messages/AddCartSuccessMessage.phtml